# Passing the value of a variable to macro in C

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I'm trying to pass the value of a variable to a macro in C, but I don't know if this is possible. Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define CONCVAR(_n) x ## _n

int main () {
   int x0, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9;
   int i;

   for (i = 0; i <= 9; i++) CONCVAR(i) = i*5;

   return 0;
}
```

Here, I'm trying to use a macro to assign a value to all x_ variables, using `##` tokens. I know I can easily achieve this with arrays, but this is for learning purposes only.

`CONCVAR(i)` is substituted to `xi`, not `x1` (if i == 1). I know how defines and macro work, it's all about substitution, but I want to know if it is possible to pass the value of i instead the letter `i` to a macro.

Comment: You should simply use arrays. It will never work this way and even if it would, there's little to be learnt from it apart from that it's simply horrible code. If you want to peak behind arrays, use pointers instead (and be prepared for lots of holes in your feet).

Comment: @delnan: This looks more like an exercise in using/understanding `##` than in using arrays, but I'm not sure. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor#Token_concatenation

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, every macro that ressembles a function, or that takes parameters, is bad programming practice.

Comment: @delnan I know it's better to use arrays, but I'm just trying to learn with this example. ;)

Comment: @Frustrated: I know it's for education purposes (that's in the question) and OP will learn something about the preprocessor about this (namely, when it's expanded). But it's still a horrible idea.

Comment: I'm curious: have you actually *tried* to compile/run this code to see what happens?

Comment: As for learning, you don't need to exercise using ##, it is a superfluous feature. You need it about as much as you need trigraphs, or any other such obscure, superfluous syntax feature.

Comment: @Frustrated Yes, CONCVAR(i) is converted to xi, and there is no such variable, so it doesn't compile.

Comment: @Lundin: Well, it *can* have it's uses. Rather rare, yes, and in those cases you might consider using a higher-level language that has the feature you're emulating anyway - but unlike trigraphs propably used by some real-world projects.

Comment: @Lundin I know it's not an important feature, but I was curious.

Comment: @delnan From what I heard through the grapewine, trigraphs were added to the standard because they had weird keyboards in Denmark, lacking some necessary symbols used in C. So yeah, everything in the language is used *somewhere* in the real world alright. But that doesn't mean that every C programmer must study trigraphs in-depth, or use them just because they exist.

Comment: @Lundin: Trigraphs were introduced because some parts of the world didn't even have ASCII-compilant charsets and keyboards back then. But this ended long long ago. I doubt that any code written in the last 20 years uses trigraphs, apart perhaps from *extremely* rare (as in, 1 in a million projects) and weird stuff. Therefore, I don't think anyone should study trigraphs. However, `#` and `##` *are* used (see for instance [google code](http://www.google.com/codesearch?hl=de&lr=&q=^%23define\+.*%3F%23%23\++lang%3Ac&sbtn=Suche)).

Comment: @Lundin, C preprocessor is an extremely useful tool, as C and C++ are a limited and limiting languages. For an inspiring showcase of `##` usage and macros in general, take a look at the LLVM and Clang sources, especially at a way .def and .inc files are used. There is no better way to do the same thing with such a limited language as C++.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Substituting the value of `i` into the macro is impossible, since macro substitutions happen before your code is compiled. If you're using GCC, you can see the pre-processor output by adding the '-E' command line argument (Note however, that you'll see all the #include's inserted in your code.)

C is a static language and you can not decide symbol names at runtime. However, what you're trying to achieve is possible if you use an array and refer to elements using subscripts. As a rule of thumb, if you have many variables like x0, x1, etc, you should probably be using a container like an array.

Answer (score 9):

No, because the *value* of `i` only exists at *run-time*.  Macro expansion happens at *compile-time*.

Answer (score 1):

No, it won't work. The C/C++ pre-processor is just that, a "pre-compile" time text processor. As such, it operates on the text found as-is in your source code.

That's why, it takes the literal text "i", pass it into your macro, expanding that into the literal text "xi" in your source code. Then that gets passed into the compiler. The compiler then starts parsing the post-processed text, finding the literal token "xi" as an undeclared variable, going belly up in the process.

You can take your sample source code and pass it to a gcc compiler (I used gcc under cygwin for example, pasting your code into a file I named *pimp.c* for lack of a better name). Then you'll get the following:

```
$ gcc pimp.c
pimp.c: In function `main':
pimp.c:9: error: `xi' undeclared (first use in this function)
pimp.c:9: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
pimp.c:9: error: for each function it appears in.)
```

In short, no, you cannot do that. To be able to do just that, then the pre-processor would have to act as an interpreter. C and C++ are (generally) not interpreted languages, and the pre-processor is not an interpreter. My suggestion would be to get very clear on the differences between compilers and interpreters (and between compiled and interpreted languages.)

Regards.